# Mudar hora e data final de acordo com a inicial

Tags: javascript, jquery

Cada vez que você seleciona uma hora inicial para o evento no Google Agenda, ele adiciona uma 1 a hora final. 
Por exemplo: Se você coloca 12:00 do dia 25/03 na inicial, na final irá aparecer 13:00 do dia 25/03.
Porém, quando você colocar 23:00 do dia 03/06 na inicial, ele muda a final para 00:00 04/06.

Gostaria de saber qual é a melhor for para fazer isso em Javascript / Jquery.

[image: Data e Hora Google Calendar]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma solução sera converter o valor de string dos textboxes de data e hora iniciais para um objeto `Date` do Javascript apenas e adicionar uma hora ao valor dele. Depois disso, é só converter de volta para duas strings e colocar o valor nos textboxes de data e hora finais. Fiz um snippet, dá um olhada.

```js
function calculaDataHoraFinal() {
  var valorDataIni = $("#data-ini").val();
  var valorHoraIni = $("#hora-ini").val();

  if (valorDataIni && valorHoraIni) {

    var partesData = valorDataIni.split("/");
    var partesHora = valorHoraIni.split(":");

    var dataIni = new Date(partesData[2], partesData[1] - 1, partesData[0], partesHora[0], partesHora[1]);
    var dataFim = new Date(dataIni.getTime());
    dataFim.setHours(dataFim.getHours() + 1);

    var partesHoraFim = dataFim.toTimeString().split(':');
    $("#data-fim").val(dataFim.toLocaleDateString());
    $("#hora-fim").val(partesHoraFim[0] + ':' + partesHoraFim[1]);

  }
}

$("#data-ini, #hora-ini").on('change', calculaDataHoraFinal);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <input id="data-ini" type="text" />
  <input id="hora-ini" type="text" />&nbsp;até&nbsp;
  <input id="data-fim" type="text" />
  <input id="hora-fim" type="text" />
</div>
```

Sei que existem métodos de ´parse` de data, assim como de formatação, mas todos dependem da localização do navegador e a definição de cultura para esses métodos não está bem implementada em todos os navegadores. Se quiser tornar as coisas mais simples, pode usar uma biblioteca de tratamento de data para Javascript como o [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/).

Answer (score 1):

```js
var entrada = document.getElementById("txt-entrada");
var saida = document.getElementById("txt-saida");

function adicionarHora() {
    // converte string em data
    var data_entrada = moment(entrada.value, "DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss");

    // define o valor da saida
    saida.value = moment(data_entrada).add(2, 'hour').format('DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.3/moment.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="txt-entrada" onkeyup="adicionarHora()" value="24/05/2015 23:00:00" placeholder="Entrada" />
<input type="text" id="txt-saida" placeholder="Saida" />
```

Utilize a biblioteca [MomentJS](http://momentjs.com/). E através do método [add()](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/add/) é possível adicionar determinados períodos a data:

Veja exemplo funcionando no [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fazv1phx/1/);

Comment: Faltava você coloca a referência para o plugin moment.js e do Jquery. Seu Jsfield não funciona, mais dei uma arrumada no seu código.